# Compare values in specific times between several days

Tags: date-and-time, conditional

I have imported csv file which is a Daily Load Diagram consisting of 3 months (1st dec 2018 to 28th feb 2019) and the values of current are taken every 10 seconds.

```
cv = FileNames["M:\\RS3710-TS1948.csv"]
{DateObject@
      StringReplace[#1, 
       x : DigitCharacter .. ~~ "." ~~ y : DigitCharacter .. ~~ "." ~~
          z : DigitCharacter .. ~~ " " ~~ rest__ :> 
        z <> "/" <> y <> "/" <> x <> " " <> 
         rest], #2} & @@@ # & /@ (Import[#, "Table", 
      "FieldSeparators" -> ";"][[2 ;;, {-2, -1}]] & /@ cv)
```

Well, since I care mainly about peak time (11:00-16:00) I would like to find a day with the highest mean value in this peak time range and once found then just basically Plot this one day from 0:00 to 23:55. There might be days which have higher values outside peak time than the day with the highest peak time values but I only care as I said about the highest mean peak time value not the highest mean value for the whole day.

I don't know which condition to use to compare dates and times together nor how I should handle this.
Could you help me with this problem? Thank you for for advices.
Here is the link for csv file with Daily Load Diagram:

https://gofile.io/?c=OH21Sm

#### Update

The posted answer works nicely for the example file I provided. However, I also tried to import a different one which has step also 10 min but taken at different times like 59:59 but it says there is failure and "The window contains no values" (see screenshot). I just rewrote that part of the code `TimeObject /@ {{10, 59, 59}, {15, 59, 59}}`.

[image: different time]

An example dataset for this case can be found here: [https://gofile.io/?c=OH21Sm](https://gofile.io/?c=WPgPC5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using [`TimeSeriesWindow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesWindow.html), [`TimeObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeObject.html) and [`TakeLargestBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeLargestBy.html): (for the query syntax, see [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html))

```
(* import the data *)
ds = Dataset@Import[
    "RS3710-TS1948.csv",
    "Table",
    "FieldSeparators" -> ";",
    HeaderLines -> 1 (* skip the first line *)
    ];

ds[(* get the two relevant columns *)
      All,
      -2 ;;
      ][
     All,
     {(* for the first column, *)
      1 -> ((* convert the string to a DateObject by splitting it, 
        reordering the parts and converting them to numbers*)
        DateObject[FromDigits /@ {#3, #2, #, ##4}] & @@
          StringSplit[#, "." | " " | ":"] &
        )
      }
     ][
    (* group the datapoints by day *)
    GroupBy[DateObject[#, "Day"] &@*First]
    ][
   All,
   TimeSeries,(* 
   convert the datasets for each day to a TimeSeries... *)
   {1 -> TimeObject} (* after converting the date to a TimeObject *)
   ][
  TakeLargestBy[(* find the day with the highest value of *)
   (* the mean of the value in the window specified *)
   Mean@Quiet[
      Check[(* 
       catch TimeSeriesWindow::tswndt messages and return {-∞} in those cases *)
       TimeSeriesWindow[#, TimeObject /@ {{11, 0, 0}, {16, 0, 0}}],
       {-∞},
       TimeSeriesWindow::tswndt
       ],
      TimeSeriesWindow::tswndt
      ] &,
      1
   ]
  ][
 First,(*get the first result *)
 DateListPlot (* and plot it *)
 ]
```

*Note:* Updated the code to handle days where no data are available in the relevant window. Essentially, we check for any `TimeSeriesWindow::tswndt` messages and return `{-∞}` in those cases, ensuring that `Mean` and `TakeLargestBy` work as intended. I have also exchanged `MaximalBy` with `TakeLargestBy`, which handles the `-∞` correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it and it works very nice. However, I also tried to import a different one which has step also 10 min but taken at different times like 59:59 but it says there is failure and The window contains no values (see pic). I just rewrote that part of the code TimeObject /@ {{10, 59, 59}, {15, 59, 59}}.

Comment: Also like to file with different time https://gofile.io/?c=WPgPC5

Comment: The issue with your new dataset is the first day which only contains a single point right before midnight. I have updated the code in the answer to handle those cases properly